# Angular httpClient - POST successful, no parameters sent

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular-httpclient

I am trying to do something very basic in my Ionic4 app - post data to an Asp.Net Web API 2 interface. The request is successful, but there is no data received on the server.

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

someAction(assetId: number) {
let asset = new FormData();
asset.append("assetId", assetId.toString());
asset.append("UserId", "1");

return this.httpClient.post(this.url + "SomeAction", asset, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' } }).toPromise();
    }
```

On the server (C#):

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Service/SomeAction")]
public HttpResponseMessage SomeAction(AccessData asset)
{
  return new HttpResponseMessage(_service.LogAsset(asset));
}
```

The `asset` object on the server is instantiated, but does not contain values sent by the client.

Also, removing/changing the headers sent results in request failing completely.

**Edit:**
Removing the header results in error 404, and also has this in the console:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://server' from origin 'http://localhost'
>   has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't
>   pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Changing the header to "multipart/form-data" results in error 415 - unsupported media type

**Edit #2:** 
This works with Postman and HTTPBot (iPhone), just not from my Ionic app

Comment: Without any other additional details how your .NET WebAPI is setup. Pretty sure your API is expecting a `JSON` content type not `x-www-form-urlencoded`. You can try adding `[FromBody]` attribute to your `AccessData` parameter.

Comment: @penleychan I suspect that too, but changing/removing that header makes the request fail - it doesn't even reach the server.

Comment: Can you show us the error that appears when you try POSTing without that content type header?

Comment: @favdev - Edited my question with more info

Comment: Are you accessing a remote server?

Comment: @favdev No, the server is my computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: I eventually fixed the issue by enabling CORS. I had enabled CORS in `web.config` and expected it to suffice, but it turns out I actually needed to install the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` package and add the `[EnableCors]` attribute to my post methods.

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the error when you remove the `Content-Type` header:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://server' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy

Comment: How does content-type affect CORS?

Answer (score 0):

I switched to using the [Ionic native http plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http) as a solution. Which is not the end of my problems, though. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56158293/ionic-4-native-http-post-with-multiple-headers) for more info.

Comment: I honestly would recommend you keep trying to use Angular Http Client. Its is faster and more powerful. Once you figure out the issue, whether on server or client side everything will work smoother.

Comment: @StephenRomero I read that the native plugin prevents the browser CORS issue and I saw that as a benefit in my case. Is there a good comparison for the features, speed, etc for both plugins that could help me choose?

Comment: Well from my experience from research, the Angular plugin is more efficient. If you plan on using Angular with your Ionic app, it will be more beneficial in the long run. I use PHP as my backend and had trouble with the CORS headers at first, but once I got the issue resolved everything worked beautifully. There are also alot more features with Angular http than Ionic.